# How to sell a single product rather than opening an entire ecommerce website

Tags: ecommerce

I have a single app product I want to sell. There are tons of e-commerce website, but these seem to be targeted to companies that sell more than one product.

Is there some solution to make an attractive website that emphasises the purchase of a single product?

Answer (score 2):

If you're only ever likely to have one product you could set up an info site, then use paypal, nochex or google checkout to take the funds, coding the necessary steps manually - for a single product this needn't be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend going with Paypal's Buy Now button. Its really easy to get set up and place on your page.

If you are looking for how to actually create the site, try finding a landing page theme on Theme Forest that you like and edit it for your product - adding in the buy now button.

Answer (score 0):

As you said app product i assume your only selling digital content.

You could give [binpress](http://www.binpress.com/) a try. You can design your whole page (called store front) there and they do the payment with your paypal or stripe (stripe.com) account.

If you need to comply with EU Vat, you could use [paddle](https://www.paddle.com/) for payment as they do the whole Eu Vat mess for you. But you would need your own page. You could look for a nice theme on themeforest or use  bootstrapstarterkit.com . They have a builder tool for roughly sketching your page.